# How to write a true if()

Tags: php, if-statement, code-formatting

I always write if statements like this:

```
if (...) {
    /* do something */
}
```

When I create topics on stackoverflow, sometimes people change this code to:

```
if (...)
{
    /* do something */
}
```

So the first `{` goes to a new line.

**Does it make sense, what's the true way?**

Comment: Both are fine.  It's just a style point, and people shouldn't really be altering your style.

Comment: Some will swear blind that the first style is the best, others that the second is the best - neither are right - they're both fine!

Comment: there is no "true way". Its totally a personal choice for the programmer....(though programmers often argue one is better over other).

Comment: @Happy I couldn't find any of your questions where the code style had been edited by someone else. Can you give an example?

Comment: I personally prefer the first. Others prefer the second. And Mike Burton's right: no one should alter your style in your sample code.

Comment: Asking "what's the true way" with respect to bracketting style is the kind of issue developers become highly emotive about and can frequently bring about "confrontation and argument". We'll see how this one pans out...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a best coding style for indentations (same line, next line)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159366/is-there-a-best-coding-style-for-indentations-same-line-next-line)

Comment: I'm tempted to change his first example, due to the irony of it. :)

Comment: @bzlm there is one or more, don't remember.

Comment: @Happy Come on, you don't have that many questions. Make an effort. :)

Comment: @Nelson, yup, one of them is definitely wrong ;)

Comment: I like 2nd approach. In other news, I like turtles.

Comment: 1TBS! 1TBS! 1TBS! .... uh, wait. I'm not supposed to encourage holy wars, am I?

Comment: This is not "subjective and argumentative". Happy is asking whether brace style makes a difference. That's a genuine question with a clear, objective answer: No, it doesn't make any real difference, it's just a personal preference. This question should not have been closed.

Comment: @TRiG: How do you square that with " **what's the true way?** " where the emphasis is in the original? People shouldn't be changing his code to conform to their stylistic expectation, but he asked for the best way. That's the brace style holy way in a nutshell.

Comment: @dmckee: Yes, he "asked for the best way" under the impression (a natural enough impression, for a newcomer, especially if people have been changing his code) that it made a difference. He was told it didn't make a difference. A simple answer to a simple question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest reading [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670).  He goes into quite depth on the subject (Devoting practically an entire chapter on it), and gives what I see as a convincing argument for #1.

He actually says not to use the second one explicitly since it fails the black box test:

```
if (blah) 
{
    //Foo
}
```

When black boxed turns into:

```
XXXXXXXXX
X
    XXX
X
```

So the opening brace is seeming like the start of the block, wheras it's not (it's just the delimiter).

Instead, he recommends either the first option (opening brace on the same line), or:

```
if (blah)
    {
    //Foo
}
```

Since it passes the black box test:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
    X
    XXXXXXX
X
```

**Note:** I can't remember if the closing delimiter is supposed to be inside the block or not...  I don't have my copy handy, so it might be:

```
if (blah) 
    {
    //Foo
    }
```

However, it all boils down to consistency.  In order for your code to be readable, you need to be consistent in how you format it.  Pick a method, and then stick to it.  Don't switch from file to file or routine to routine.  So long as you're consistent and actually format it, don't worry about it...

Answer (score 4):

Whitespace doesn't matter in PHP, so use whichever style you like better (or whatever style the project you're working on or company you work for uses to keep things consistent). Both forms are completely equivalent from the PHP interpreter's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that programmers have debated for ages. It is all up to your individual style and preference. Both ways are "Proper PHP".

Answer (score 2):

Either. The "right" one depends entirely on your coding style. I recommend you follow the one you prefer, unless you are working on existing code in which case you should follow that code's convention.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally the coders preference. Some projects have coding standards, such as Zend Framework or Company's will require it one way or the other. If you are coding for someone else or your company, ask for the standards. If you are helping with an open source project, such as Zend Framework, you would read their documentation on how you should format your code. If you are doing it for yourself, pick the way you prefer and stick to it / be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to go on a new line, but some people consider it best practice to do so. It's just a matter of readability, and should therefore be tailored to best suit you or the team you're working with. **There is no true way**.